# Printing commands and exporting it to XLS

Tags: r, xlsx

Good afternoon,

Is there any way, to create a XLS document from printing data on the console?

I am using the package gapminder, and I will like to know if there is a way, when i print some information on the screen to select the first rows using head for example.

```r
> head(gapminder)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
  <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.
2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.
3 Afghanistan Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.
4 Afghanistan Asia       1967    34.0 11537966      836.
5 Afghanistan Asia       1972    36.1 13079460      740.
6 Afghanistan Asia       1977    38.4 14880372      786.
```

I will like to create a XLS file with this content.

Thank you in advanced.

Im trying to create a XLS document with the content from the output of a function.

Comment: The library `writexl` provides the `write_xlsx` function. You could use this to create your output file. `write_xlsx(df, "filename.xlsx")`

Comment: "printing data on the console" and "saving to a file" are generally not a good idea. Is there a reason you prefer to not use `writexl::write_xlsx` or `openxlsx::write.xlsx` directly on the data? When something is printed on the console, it often results in "simplifying" the display for aesthetic purposes, and using that rendered data as the whole truth would be problematic. Take for example `data.frame(x=pi)`, where the number of decimal places displayed is not the same as the precision stored in the actual object.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much for your fast answer ! I didnt thought about what you said, and makes totally sense to me, thank you again  :)